# EE 2.9.0 || Template Routing

Tags: templates, low

How would one use Template Routing to route this:

http://MYDOMAINNAME.COM/tournaments/public-schedule/archives/2014/10/

To a Structure template of my choosing? I have this currently set:

[image]

Which states:

GROUP: templates
TEMPLATE: events

I want to route the Archives/year/month there then run a conditional that will display the low archive tag there. I know how to do this with CraftCMS, but EE's documentation really stinks regarding template routing and I can't find any good posts of this online either.

Thanks for the help community!

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't say the documentation stinks, there's an [example near the top of the page](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/template_routes.html#usage) under **Usage** close to what you want.

In your case, it looks like you probably want:

```
/tournaments/public-schedule/archives/{year:regex[(\d{4})]}/{month:regex[(\d{2})]}/
```

Then you will access your [segment variables](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/template_routes.html#segment-variables-and-paths) with `{segment:year}` and `{segment:month}`.

Comment: That did it! Appreciate the assist on this one!

Comment: You don't know off hand if you can have TWO routes for one template do you?

Comment: Sorry I don't. Haven't gotten that advanced with it myself.